# How do I prevent resources from being destroyed during the Azure DevOps Terraform Plan Step?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have inherited some reponsibilities and by that I mean managing Terraform in AzureDevOps Release Pipeline deployments.

I am using the Terraform Task with the following steps:
init
validate
plan
apply

But during the plan output I can see a number of resources being destroyed that I don't want to be removed.

```
azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv_secret_az_backup_storage_account_name will be destroyed
```

I was looking for a way to disable any resource destruction during the creation of the tfstate file but there doesn't appear to be a way in Azure DevOps. So my best option would be I suppose resorted to amending the underlying main.tf script but I don't know how.

This is one of the resources being removed. I have renamed to keep anonymity. Can anyone suggestion a solution to my dilemma?

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv_secret_az_storage_account_name" {
  name         = "storage-account-name"
  value        = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_storage_account.storage_account]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plan` phase doesn't destroy your resource nor creates new. It does inform you what will happen when you run `apply`.

so

> azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv_secret_az_backup_storage_account_name will be destroyed

this just says that your storage account will be destroyed if you run apply.

But since it tries to remove, it means that terrafrom keeps information bout this resource in state. So it was created be terraform and now if you want to put it out of the scope here - I mean you don't want to have it longer maintained by your teffafrom script you can use [`state rm` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html).

> Items removed from the Terraform state are not physically destroyed. Items removed from the Terraform state are only no longer managed by Terraform. For example, if you remove an AWS instance from the state, the AWS instance will continue running, but terraform plan will no longer see that instance.

Comment: Hello and thanks for responding. How would that look in the code block in my tf script? Also, because I want tf to be able to handle the resource in future, would removing the state rm command reintroduce the state for that resource?

Comment: To reintroduce you need to use `terraform state mv` and you should not to put it in any script. It is a command so you should run it as any command, from command line. It will work against your configured backend and be careful with this and provide an argument to create a backup.

Comment: @DonDraper Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?